# iOS5 iPhone Safari - stop native scrollbar from disappearing

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios5, mobile-safari

I'm working on webpage for iPhone devices. This page has a div with overflow property set as below to implement native scrolling provided in iOS5.

```
.nativeScroll {
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
   overflow:auto;
   height:200px;
}
```

With above CSS style, scrolling is working fine. But scrollbar appears only when user touches the div and tries to scroll. Now the problem when untouched the scrollbar disappears which is default implementation. In this case, it looks like the div doesn't have any overflow content. So user may never bother to scroll.

So is it possible to make scrollbar always visible whether or not the div has touch?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try and add this rule : `overflow-y: scroll;` ?

Comment: I tried "overflow:scroll". But it doesn't make scrollbar visible.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I think there is no "clean" way to do it. But, you can use a third party lib [like iScroll.](http://cubiq.org/iscroll)

On the homepage, you can find a reference to the `hideScrollbar`. Its default value is `true`. You can set it to `false` for your needs.

Comment: We already have iscroll library implemented. I'm trying to get rid off it due to lots of side-effects created by this library. One of the main problem is iScroll doesn't allow user selections like copy/paste.

Comment: did you try to add this css rule `-webkit-user-select:none;` or `-webkit-user-select:auto;` to allow the copy/paste ?

Comment: If i'm correct iScroll prevents default behavior on touch start.  http://groups.google.com/group/iscroll/browse_thread/thread/cb1b2995cf983bda

Comment: There is a workaround for this [at this location](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-3-5-adds-scrolltoelement) where it's said that all you have to do is that _you may try to remove the preventdefault from touchstart and place it on touchmove_

Comment: I've already tried that solution for iScroll4. But it didn't help. Thanks Zakaria for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not post any code. Thanks for your help though. I'm still looking for alternatives.